# Appending to cstring after assigning the first index

Tags: c, winapi

The output of this example is ...

> HC:\Projects\cppexample.exeello world.

Why the path to the current executable was pushed in the string?

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE 
#endif


    #include <Windows.h>

    int main()
    {
        TCHAR string[255];
        string[0]=TEXT('H');
        wcscat(string,TEXT("ello world"));

        MessageBox(0,string,0,0);

        system("Pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you did not end the "string" "H" with a null-byte. Therefore `wcscat` appends to where it finds the first null-byte in your (uninitialized) array, which happened to contain the executable path (and one byte of something else before that).

Answer (score 3):

`string` has no null terminating character before the call to [`wcscat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1x0y282%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and `wcscat()` requires the destination string to be null terminated:

```
strDestination 
    Null-terminated destination string.
```

Change to:

```
TCHAR string[255] = TEXT("");
string[0]=TEXT('H');
```

or:

```
TCHAR string[255] = TEXT("H");
```

or:

```
TCHAR string[255];
string[0]=TEXT('H');
string[0]=TEXT('\0');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to terminate string array with `'\0'`. Update code like.

```
string[0]=TEXT('H');
string[1]=TEXT('\0');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem:

```
string[0]=TEXT('H');
wcscat(string,TEXT("ello world"));
```

and
    uninitialized `TCHAR string[255];`

This should solve your problem:

```
wmemset(string,TEXT('\0'), 255);
string[0]=TEXT('H');
string[1]=TEXT('\0');
wcscat(string,TEXT("ello world"));
```

So, now wcscat() will happily concatenate two Null-terminated strings, "H" and "ello,World". And not throw in some garbage values.

Avoid using, for buffer security:
`wchar_t *wcscat(
   wchar_t *strDestination,
   const wchar_t *strSource 
);`

Instead use:
`wchar_t *wcsncat(
   wchar_t *strDest,
   const wchar_t *strSource,
   size_t count 
);`

Where,

*strDest

    Null-terminated destination string.

 strSource

    Null-terminated source string.

 count

    Number of characters to append.*